# What path do I use for pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, pyspark

I have spark installed.  And, I can go into the `bin` folder within my spark version, and run `./spark-shell` and it runs correctly.

But, for some reason, I am unable to launch `pyspark` and any of the submodules.

So, I go into `bin` and launch `./pyspark` and it tells me that my path is incorrect.

The current path I have for `PYSPARK_PYTHON` is the same as where I'm running the `pyspark` executable script from.

What is the correct path for `PYSPARK_PYTHON`?  Shouldn't it be the path that leads to the executable script called `pyspark` in the `bin` folder of the spark version?

That's the path that I have now, but it tells me `env: <full PYSPARK_PYTHON path> no such file or directory`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct path for PYSPARK_PYTHON?  Shouldn't it be the path that leads to the executable script called pyspark in the bin folder of the spark version?

No, it shouldn't. It should point to a Python executable you want to use with Spark (for example output from `which python`. If you don't want to use custom interpreter just ignore it. Spark will use the first Python interpreter available on your system `PATH`.