# Update the python version running spark Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to setup my environment for spark with python. I get a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop , then I installed the spark version 1.6.2 and now I'm struggling to configure the python version 3.5.

My current pyspark is running like:

[image]

My available python versions are - ls /usr/bin/ | grep python

[image]

I tried to edit the file .bashrc to add the variable PYSPARK_PYTHON

[image]

I appreciate thanks so much your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `pyspark` at the end and you'll be good

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.5
```

although it would be better to set this in

```
$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh
```

Reference [What path do I use for pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533786)